# After Effects precomposing and text issue (what is the # icon?)

Tags: animation, adobe-after-effects

I've been working in a composition containing 65% opacity Shape layer background and some animated text layers on it.
Then I'm trying to paste this composition into another one, but there I can see only that semitransparent rectangle in it!

At the same time, my text layers have some strange marks - torquoise "#" symbols. What do they mean?[image: What does those "#" icons mean?]

Comment: Should I add something to the answer I've missed?

Comment: Nope, thank you so much! The only problem here was caused by these "guides". You can't imagine how happy I am now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### [#]  Guide Layers

are only **visible in the current composition**, but not in other compositions or the final render. For e.g. In terms of working in a subcomposition, it can be useful to **see the footage of the main composition**. In this case, you can copy the footage to the subcomposition and turn it into a guide layer by 
*Selecting the Layer*, go to *Layer > Guide Layer* **or** *Right Click > Guide Layer* (to enable or disable it).

[Adobe](http://www.adobepress.com/articles/article.asp?p=1648576&seqNum=2) says:

> Like adjustment layers, guide layers are standard layers with special
>   status. A guide layer appears in the current composition but not in
>   any subsequent compositions or the final render (unless it is
>   specifically overridden in Render Settings.)

Related:

- http://masteringfilm.com/creating-motion-graphics-with-after-effects-hidden-gems-chapter-6-layer-essentials/
- http://www.adobepress.com/articles/article.asp?p=1648576&seqNum=2